# How to make breeze recognize a successful retried savechanges() request

Tags: angularjs, breeze, interceptor

I have an interceptor which automatically detect a 401 error, obtains a new token the re-fires the request...

The issue is that at the time it does this breeze entity manager have also obtain this error an unaware that the request is redone causing duplicates on the next save changes.

I have tried and cant seem to find the way to notify breeze that the entities where saved..

The <del>request</del> response is intercepted by this

```
  var responseError = function (rejection) {

        var authService = $injector.get("auth");
        var authData = localStorageService.get("authorizationData");

        if (rejection.status === 401) {
            if (authData && authData.refreshToken) {
                authService.refreshToken()
                    .then(function () {
                        var $http = $injector.get("$http");
                        return $http(rejection.config);
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        $location.path("/login");
                        return error;
                    });
            }
            else {
                authService.logOut();
                $location.path("/login");
            }

        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    };
```

Any way to notify breeze that the retry was a success?

Comment: hm, not so sure if I'm getting the same error while saving. the breez entity again. I return a deferred promise, if the rejection status is 401 and append the rejected request to a buffer. after successful authentication the request is resent and the deferred promise is resolved.

Comment: I was not getting the same error.. the problem is that breeze dont acknowledge that entities(when the rejected request is resend successfully) are saved which result in sending them again next time savechanges() is called.. making duplicates @RaphaelMüller

Comment: Is this a `$http` interceptor? I can't tell how you have this hooked up. If it's a [`$http` interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors), the `EntityManager` should never know that you took an extra round-trip to refresh the token.  Creating a working example (e.g., a plunker) would help us better understand your situation.

Comment: Ok ... I see that you are using a `$http` interceptor ... and I think I see the problem. See my answer.

Comment: thanks that worked flawlessly... +1 and accepted your answer but now i am feeling stupid for overseeing this for days. @Ward

Comment: We all do that. We all need fresh eyes. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your interceptor is ***always*** falling through to the last line and returning the original 401 rejection.

I think you are missing the return statement that would return the retry promise instead:

```
if (rejection.status === 401) {
    if (authData && authData.refreshToken) {
        return authService.refreshToken().
        ...
```